# Stack overflow error in endpoints method

Tags: android, stack-overflow, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing a google app engine powered android app using endpoints and in the api which I am writing I keep getting stack overflow errors for no apparent reason.

So far here are the 2 methods in my endpoint api class:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile")
public Profile saveProfile(@Named("userId") String userId,
                               @Named("firstName") String firstName,
                               @Named("lastName") String lastName,
                               @Named("birthday") String birthday) {

        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, userId)).now();
        if (profile == null) {
            profile = new Profile(userId, firstName, lastName, birthday);
        } else {
            profile.updateProfile(firstName, lastName, birthday);
        }
        ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
        return profile;
    }

@ApiMethod(name = "getSuggestedFriends")
public List<Profile> getSuggestedFriends(@Named("userId") String userId) {

    Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, userId)).now();
    if (profile != null) {
        /**
         * Queries for users with same last name as you (presumably family).
         */
        Query<Profile> sameLastName = ofy().load().type(Profile.class).order("birthday");
        sameLastName = sameLastName.filter("lastName =", profile.getLastName());

        /**
         * Gets the friends of your friends.
         */
        List<Profile> suggestedFriends = new ArrayList<>(0);
        for (Profile friend : profile.getFriends()) {
            for (Profile friendOfFriend : friend.getFriends()) {
                if (!profile.getFriends().contains(friendOfFriend))
                    suggestedFriends.add(friendOfFriend);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Merge the 2 lists into 1 list of suggested friends.
         */
        for (Profile suggestedFriend : sameLastName) {
            if (!profile.getFriends().contains(suggestedFriend))
                suggestedFriends.add(suggestedFriend);
        }
        return suggestedFriends;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Can someone offer some insight and a solution as to why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

Most of the stacktrace (it is very long):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.toArray(AnnotationParser.java:865)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1139)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.FieldProperty.<init>(FieldProperty.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.findKeyFields(KeyMetadata.java:77)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.<init>(KeyMetadata.java:50)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:64)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CollectionTranslatorFactory.create(CollectionTranslatorFactory.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace? It might be helpful.

Comment: Could it be a bad objectify configuration?  It looks like there's some kind of circular reference problem happening as it tries to build its translators.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with this kind of situation:

```
public class Entity
{
    private List<Entity> children;
}
```

Depending on your situation you could try @Serialize'ing children.